# Search MongoDB by title not id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to have my route pull the title from the url for a blog app. I got it working using `id` but can't figure out the title. I know I can't do `findById()` but instead use `find()`. How do I tailor my query to find the title.

**Route**

```
  app.get("/blogs/:title", function(req, res) {
    Blog.find(req.params.title, function(err, foundBlog){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/blogs");
        } else {
            res.render("show", {blog: foundBlog});
        }
    });
  });
```

**schema**

```
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    body: String,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    author: {
      id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"
      },
      email: String
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an object with your schema's key into the `find()` method:

```
  app.get("/blogs/:title", function(req, res) {
    Blog.find({ title: req.params.title }, function(err, foundBlog){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/blogs");
        } else {
            res.render("show", {blog: foundBlog});
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work, I get a empty array when I `console.log()` it out to check.

Comment: Then you have more than that issue. Make sure `req.params.title` is whatever you expect and that a document with exactly this title does exist.